# QWC2 searching highlight

Tags: qgis, react, qwc2

I create api function for searing parcels and create call from SearchProviders. All it's working fine when i try to search, but when I select object form searchbox its only zoom map to the parcel but don't highlight the parcel polygon. Also in qgis project I checked the option Add geometry to feature response
This is my searchprovider

```
function ParcelLocationSearch(text, requestId, searchOptions, dispatch) {
    axios.get("http://127.0.0.1:3003/v1/query/parcel?columns=id%2Cnum_parcel%2Ckat_opst_1%2CST_Extent(geom)%20as%20bbox&filter=num_parcel%20like%20'%25"+text+"%25'&sort=num_parcel&group=id%2Cnum_parcel%2Ckat_opst_1" )
    .then(response => dispatch(ParcelLocationSearchResults(response.data, requestId)));
}

function ParcelResultGeometry(resultItem, callback)
{
   
     axios.get("http://127.0.0.1:3003/v1/query/parcel?columns=ST_AsText(geom)%20as%20geom&filter=id%3D"+text)
    .then(response => callback(resultItem, response.data, "EPSG:4326"));
}

function ParcelLocationSearchResults(obj, requestId)
{
    let results = [];
    let currentgroup = null;
    let resultGroups = {};
    let groupcounter = 0;
    let counter = 0;

    (obj || []).map(entry => {
      
        resultString = (entry.bbox.replace('BOX(','').replace(')','').replace(' ',',').replace(' ',',')).split(',');
       
        let x = 0.5 * (parseFloat(resultString[0]) + parseFloat(resultString[2]));
        let y = 0.5 * (parseFloat(resultString[1]) + parseFloat(resultString[3]));
        if(groupcounter ==0) {
        currentgroup = {
            id: "ustergroup" + (groupcounter++),
            title: entry.displaytext,
            items: []
        };
        results.push(currentgroup);
    }
      else  {
         
            currentgroup.items.push({
            id: entry.id,
        
            layer:"parcel",
            text: entry.num_parcel,
            label:entry.num_parcel,
            title:entry.num_parcel,
            marker:true,
            x: 0.5 * (parseFloat(resultString[0]) + parseFloat(resultString[2])),
            y: 0.5 * 0.5 * (parseFloat(resultString[1]) + parseFloat(resultString[3])),
            crs: "EPSG:4326",
            bbox: [x, y, x, y],
            provider: "Parcel"
        });
    }
    });

    return addSearchResults({data: results, provider: "Parcel", reqId: requestId}, true);
}
SearchProviders: {
        "coordinates": {
            labelmsgid: "search.coordinates",
            onSearch: coordinatesSearch
        },
        "Parcel": {
            label: "parcels",
            onSearch: ParcelLocationSearch,
            getResultGeometry: ParcelResultGeometry
}
}
```